# Rest request body to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: php, postman

I'm trying to pass request body into a curl call and I'm stuck.

I in the drupal workflow rule I have defined a data field for the body parameters I need to call a service as key value pairs.The dump for the $data variable looks as such...

```
artifact1=valueXYZ
artifact2=value123
```

My postman output for the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is a string

```
  i.e.(------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\artifact1\r\n\r\nvalueXYZ\r\n)
```

In PHP how do I get `artifact1=valueXYZ` to into a format for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`?

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use an array and then use PHP `http_build_query()` function:

```
      $array_values['artifact1'] = "valueXYZ";
      $array_values['artifact2'] = "value123";
      $fields = http_build_query($array_values);
      $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => $url,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields,
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "cache-control: no-cache"
          ),
      ));

      $response = curl_exec($curl);
      $err = curl_error($curl);

      curl_close($curl);
```

Then you receive your values like this:

```
$artifact1 = $_POST['artifact1'];
$artifact2 = $_POST['artifact2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an array:

```
$arr = array('art1' => 'value1','art2' => 'value2');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arr);
```